# Local Storage in Omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

Is there a local storage in Omnet++.A storage where I could save some data.
I don't want to use a database like MySQL or Oracle for the same purpose.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you found out so far?  We are not Google..

Answer (score 1):

It is better to follow the official tutorial of OMNeT++(https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/). You can take a look at the chapter 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ provides facilities to store scalar and vector data. Vector data is basically a series of time stamped values. Other than that, you are on your own. You can save to files, use databases etc.